# Office 2003 Service Pack 3- Not able to install

Tags: installation, sp3, microsoft-office-2003

I am trying to install Office 2003 SP3 on a windows 2003 EE server (used as a terminal server) which already have office 2003 SP2.

I am getting an error that says "Update can not be applied".

Below are the eventviewer entries for Application:

1. _

   ```
   Event Type: Warning
   Event Source: MsiInstaller
   Event Category: None
   Event ID: 1015
   Date:  1-2-2010
   Time:  5:51:22
   User:  Domain\domainadmin
   Computer: TER01
   Description:
   Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x800401F0
   ```

   For more information, see Help and Support Center at     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
2. _

   ```
   Event Type: Information
   Event Source: MsiInstaller
   Event Category: None
   Event ID: 11708
   Date:  1-2-2010
   Time:  5:52:23
   User:  Domain\domainadmin
   Computer: TER01
   Description:
   Product: Microsoft Office Professional Edition 2003 -- Installation failed.
   ```

   For more information, see Help and Support Center at     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

   ```
   Data:
   0000: 7b 39 30 31 31 30 34 30   {9011040
   0008: 39 2d 36 30 30 30 2d 31   9-6000-1
   0010: 31 44 33 2d 38 43 46 45   1D3-8CFE
   0018: 2d 30 31 35 30 30 34 38   -0150048
   0020: 33 38 33 43 39 7d         383C9}
   ```
3. _

   ```
   Event Type: Information
   Event Source: McLogEvent
   Event Category: None
   Event ID: 257
   Date:  1-2-2010
   Time:  5:52:23
   User:  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
   Computer: TER01
   Description:
   Would be blocked by access protection rule  (rule is in warn-only mode) (Common         Standard Protection:Prevent common programs from running files from the Temp folder).
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the app is running from the Temp folder.  Is that correct? Is there an AV scanner with a rule that prevents such execution?  McLogEvent would point to McAfee